# How to monitor a thread in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm having a kafka consumer which is running in a thread in my django application, I want to apply some monitoring and alerting on that thread. So how can I add thread monitoring (check state if it is alive or dead) and if thread is dead then need to raise an alert.

I have tried monitoring by creating scheduler which runs every 10 mins and calls thread.is_alive() method. But the problem is the scheduler is running in a different process and unable to access main process' s thread. So how can I resolve this?

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case python thread was unpredictable and controlling them was so hard. I used multiple instances (in K8s increased the replica number to partition number and in an older version without k8s increased the supervisor numprocs to the number of Kafka partion)

Comment: @Mohammadsadeghborouny So What's the final solution you applied? I just need to notify if the thread dies for all pods.

Comment: I run each worker on the different pods and monitor them with grafana (it worked for me and I could easily increase the number of replicas and monitor them).

Comment: @Mohammadsadeghborouny Can you please share some sample code snippets or any blog/post so that I can try this?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor a thread in Python, you can use the threading module, which is a built-in module in Python that provides a number of functions for working with threads. Here is an example of how you can use the threading module to monitor a thread:

```
import threading

def my_function():

  my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_function)

  my_thread.start()
   
  if my_thread.is_alive():
     # Do something
```

The threading module provides a number of other functions and methods that you can use to monitor and control threads, such as join(), isDaemon(), and setDaemon(). For more information, you can read the official Python documentation for the threading module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.

Comment: Hi @Pranav J. B Thanks for the answer. The issue is that I need to trigger an alert if the thread goes down due to some reason, I can't use scheduler because it runs in a different process and can't access main process's thread.

Comment: If you need to trigger an alert if a thread goes down due to some reason, one option you can consider is using a flag variable in the main process to signal the status of the thread. You can then check the value of this flag variable periodically in the main process to determine if the thread is still running or if it has stopped. Alternatively, you could use a Queue or a Condition object to communicate between the main process and the worker thread and signal when the thread has stopped.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.